# Why does Xcode InterfaceBuilder show duplicate values for alignment constraints?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

When I examine my label in InterfaceBuilder I see duplicate values but I'm not sure why or how I can remove them.

In the image you on the right you can see:
`Align Center X to: Superview` appears twice for the MainLabel ("FirstView").

Why is that?
Is there a way to delete the extra one?  When I click the Edit button there is not an option to delete.

I also notice that there is a constraint that shows

```
Bottom space to MainLabel 
Equals: Default

Bottom space to MainLabel 
Equals: 8
```

[image: duplicate items]

Also, it appears that these are constraints but these duplicates do not seem to show up in my constraints anywhere that I can see.  Why is that?

[image: all constraints]

I believe I'm running the most current version of Xcode:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you double click on the constraint you wish to delete it should highlight it in the storyboard navigator on the left hand side of the storyboard, you can delete it from there.

[image]

Comment: Thanks that got me there.  Didn't know about double-click on that item.  That helps me match them up.

Comment: @raddevus No problem